# Python Наследовние

Tags: python-3.x, ооп, наследование

Добрый! Начал изучать тему наследования на python, в книге был пример:

```
#класс с конструктором
class Square:
    width = 0
    height = 0
    def area(self): #каждый метод должен принемать хотя бы один параметр (self) что бы получить ссылку на самого себя
        return self.width * self.height
    def __init__(self, width, height): #констурктор класса, self самособой обязателен 
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

sq = Square(100, 40)
print(sq.area())

#Наследование 
class Cube(Square):
    z = 0
    def __init__(self, width, height, z):
        Square.__init__(self, width, height)
        self.z = z
    def volume(self):
        return self.area(self) * self.z

c = Cube(100,40,5)
a = c.area()
print(a)

v = c.volume()
print(c)
```

Во время выполнения происходит ошибка:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-80ae5ab1a692> in <module>()
     25 print(a)
     26 
---> 27 v = c.volume()
     28 print(c)

<ipython-input-25-80ae5ab1a692> in volume(self)
     19         self.z = z
     20     def volume(self):
---> 21         return self.area(self) * self.z
     22 
     23 c = Cube(100,40,5)

TypeError: area() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Прошу объяснить почему не работает

```
return self.area(self) * self.z
```

Если не сложно то максимально подробного, для максимального понимания процессов проходящих внутри

Comment: Вместо area(self) используете area(), т.к. при self.area(), self автоматически передается в первый аргумент метода класса. Исключение ведь и пишет, что ожидается 1 параметр, а передано было 2

Comment: `Square.__init__` Записывает переменные в Square. Они не доступны в Cube

Comment: Я пробовал использовать конструкцию вида: return self.area() * self.z Но в таком случае вывод <__main__.Cube object at 0x0000017DE39A7BE0> как я понимаю это ссылка на объект.

Comment: self.area() == Square.area(self)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Square:
    width = 0
    height = 0
    def area(self): #каждый метод должен принемать хотя бы один параметр (self) что бы получить ссылку на самого себя
        return self.width * self.height
    def __init__(self, width, height): #констурктор класса, self самособой обязателен 
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

sq = Square(100, 40)
print(sq.area())

#Наследование 
class Cube(Square):
    z = 0
    def __init__(self, width, height, z):
        Square.__init__(self, width, height)
        self.z = z
    def volume(self):
        return self.area() * self.z

c = Cube(100,40,5)
a = c.area()
print(a)

v = c.volume()
print(v)
```

> 4000  4000  20000

Неточность - вывод с а не v. И вызов area - не надо снова передавать self

Comment: Спасибо большое вам, опечатался. В книге тоже по ходу опечатка, ибо там было написано  self.area(self) * self.z, это я точно проверил раз 15

Comment: Читай да проверяй! Пока сам код не скопировал - так и не понял, шо за глюки